# windbg:how to get a symbol's source file name?

Tags: debugging, windbg

suppose I got a symbol foo!bar_func, so how can I get the source file of this symbol function?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have symbols setup and line number information is available, then command `ln` (which stands for "List Nearest symbols") would help you. E.g.:

```
0:000> ln MyProgram!main
c:\scratch\MyProgram\program.cpp(224)
(000819d0)   MyProgram!main   |  (00081e10)   MyProgram!time
Exact matches:
0:000>
```